# Database monitor software

Tags: neo4j

I Was wondering, whether there is some app, internet browser extension or some system pop-up message that tells you if the certain database is down. Or maybe possibility of mobile text message warning.

Is there some software like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can monitor the Neo4j database with [Halin App](https://github.com/moxious/halin).**

Halin doesn't have some of the features you are looking for like pop-ups and mobile texts.

**Following are the primary features of Halin:**

1. Performance monitoring (system load, memory usage)
2. Checks your Neo4j configuration and finds problems, makes
   suggestions on how to improve.
3. Works with both Neo4j Enterprise and Neo4j Community, clusters and
   stand-alone.
4. User & Role Management